# How to make command run when I open terminal

Tags: command-line

I am new to Ubuntu and am trying to learn the terminal. This may be a very basic question however, I have a program that I type in rat to run. 
However, before I can type in rat to run the program, I have to go to
`/home/name/file`

and then type in:

```
source install/env_rat-dev.sh
```

Could I have those beginning steps happen when I open terminal so I do not have to do it every time?

Thanks so much for any help
.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
source install/env_rat-dev.sh
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file.

`~/.bashrc` is executed every time a new terminal is opened.

> [bash manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)
>
> ~/.bashrc
>       The individual per-interactive-shell startup file

Comment: The path should be probably `/home/name/file/install/env_rat-dev.sh`.